# pandas - rolling sum last seven days over different rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Starting from this data frame:

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01. | 2 |
| 2 | 01.01. | 3 |
| 1 | 01.03. | 5 |
| 2 | 01.03. | 3 |
| 1 | 01.09. | 5 |
| 2 | 01.09. | 2 |
| 1 | 01.10. | 5 |
| 2 | 01.10. | 2 |

I would like to get a weekly sum of value:

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01. | 2 |
| 2 | 01.01. | 3 |
| 1 | 01.03. | 7 |
| 2 | 01.03. | 6 |
| 1 | 01.09. | 10 |
| 2 | 01.09. | 5 |
| 1 | 01.10. | 15 |
| 2 | 01.10. | 8 |

I use this command, but it is not working:
`df['value'] = df.groupby('id')['value'].rolling(7).sum()`

Any ideas?

Comment: This link seems to resolve the ```TypeError: incompatible index``` error: http://47.112.232.56/a/stackoverflow/en/625b00b2f96d3b7ac02b9c08.html

But when I adapt my code to the following 

```df.groupby('id')['value'].rolling(7).sum().reset_index().set_index('level_1').drop('id',axis=1)```

, I get only NA as entries

Comment: Unfurtunately what you are doing friendo is wrongerino. You see rolling, acts through your rows and account for exactly 7 of them. So you are not counting , the sum of values in that day. You are accounting by 7 rows

Answer (score 0):

You can do `groupby` and `apply`.

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m.%d.')
df['value'] = (df.groupby('id', as_index=False, group_keys=False)
               .apply(lambda g: g.rolling('7D', on='date')['value'].sum()))
```

Note that for `1900-01-10`, the rolling window is `1900-01-04`, `1900-01-05`...`1900-01-10`

```
print(df)

   id       date  value
0   1 1900-01-01    2.0
1   2 1900-01-01    3.0
2   1 1900-01-03    7.0
3   2 1900-01-03    6.0
4   1 1900-01-09   10.0
5   2 1900-01-09    5.0
6   1 1900-01-10   10.0
7   2 1900-01-10    4.0
```